# _OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have Researched [This Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#prerequisites.) Followed all step But this strange error

> **Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SFSafariViewController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileAds(flat-x86_64)**
>
> **ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

```
IOS SDK is 8.4 and xcode version is 6.4.
```

If you need to support iOS 6 instead of 7, you can use the standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK (without Firebase; prerequisites: `Xcode 5.1+ and iOS 6+` deployment target).

am not want to upgrade my xcode not even want to use cocoapods. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are using IOS SDK 8.4, but `SFSafariViewController` is only available since iOS 9 SDK

More info you can find here: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller

Comment: If you need to support iOS 6 instead of 7, you can use the standalone Google Mobile Ads SDK (without Firebase; prerequisites: Xcode 5.1+ and iOS 6+ deployment target). i have used google mobile sdk Without firebase

Comment: At this type of questions having only this Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by using an older version of Google Mobile Ads SDK.

My configuration is iOS 8.4 and xCode 6.3

First, i tried Google SDK v7.8 as Google tutorial suggest and i got the same errors as you get. Then, i uninstalled SDK 7.8 and installed version 6.12.2 of Google SDK, tried again and everything worked fine this time.

I used CocoaPods but i guess you can download Google Mobile Ads SDK 6.X on the Internet.

Regards,
Jose